# Remove Same Character once from two different string

Tags: php, string, replace

I need help in PHP Script.

I have two strings.

```
$string1 = "asdfgf";
$string2 = "asdfgasdg";
```

After removing the same character from both string once,

```
$string1 = "f";
$string2 = "asdg";
```

Another Two Strings example

```
$string1 = "sthnfr";
$string2 = "iserr";
```

Output

```
$string1 = "thnf"; // s and r removed
$string2 = "ier"; // s and r removed
```

I tried str_replace which replace all the all the characters.
Thanks for your helps

Comment: Hope you can modify your question and add a few other instances.. Tim's post definitely checks out for `$string1 = "asdfgf";$string2 = "asdfgasdg";` replacement since it seemed like a direct position character matching, so if there are other instances, kindly add them..

Comment: @Kamini:  I don't see what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you give more of an explanation?

Comment: It is something called "Flames" - School Game. I am trying to do it. I have edited question

Comment: So you want to be able to remove multiple character(s)/string sequences from more than one input string? In your second example, how do you envision passing the `s` and `r` to the string/character-removal function, given that they're not connected? Also, if this a 'school game' that you '[are] trying to do,' what have you attempted so far and what went wrong?

Comment: But the Flames game removes all instances of letters that are the same in each name..

Comment: Character position is not a issue. string1 and string 2 have "r" and "s". So those common character must be removed. At the same time, string2 preserve another "r".

Comment: @David Thomas There are few more steps on this game. I have finished other parts. This is the first step i need to finish the game.

Comment: Reading the comment above, from @Nonym, I'm assuming you want to remove all characters shared by both input strings, regardless of position?

Comment: Regardless of position, I want to remove same character from both string only once. In my second example, We keep the "r" in string2. If string1 has one more "r", then we will remove both "r" in both strings.

Comment: I finished the script. Thanks for your help. I used two for loops with break to remove the characters.

Comment: @Kamini:  I just added a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string2 = "sthnfr";
$string1 = "iserr";

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string1); )
{
    if(($pos = strpos($string2, $string1[$i])) !== false)
    {
        $string1 = substr($string1, 0, $i) . substr($string1, $i + 1);
        $string2 = substr($string2, 0, $pos) . substr($string2, $pos + 1);
        continue;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Why not pack `$i++` up in the `for()`?  It is designed for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate each character in the first string (use `mb_str_split()` from PHP7.4 if you are processing strings with multibyte characters).
2. Replace the first occurrence of the isolated character in the second string with an empty string; limit the replacements to 1; and temporarily store the the success of the replacement in `$count`. `preg_quote()` is used to stabilize the pattern and protect it from characters with special meaning to the regex engine.  Again, if multibyte characters are possible, add the `u` pattern modifier after the last `/` in the first parameter of `preg_replace()`.
3. If `$count` is `0`, then there was no match and the isolated character should be appended to the iteratively rebuilt `$newA` string.

Using this technique, the first string only grows larger as not-found characters are encountered and the second string only gets smaller as found characters are encountered. In other words, for every character iterated, either the seconds string loses a character or the new first string gains a character.

This technique is built to sanitize shared characters in both strings regardless of the order/position of the characters in the strings.  It is also very easy to extend to cover multibyte scenarios.

Function: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bsBiM))

```
function removeSharedCharacters(string $a, string $b): array {
    $newA = '';
    foreach (str_split($a) as $char) {
        $b = preg_replace('/' . preg_quote($char, '/') . '/', '', $b, 1, $count);
        if (!$count) {
            $newA .= $char;
        }
    }
    return [$newA, $b];    
}
```

Test cases and function call:

```
$tests = [
    ["asdfgf", "asdfgasdg"],
    ["sthnfr", "iserr"],
    ["acegik", "jihgfedcba"]
];

foreach ($tests as $pair) {
    var_export(removeSharedCharacters(...$pair));
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'f',
  1 => 'asdg',
)
---
array (
  0 => 'thnf',
  1 => 'ier',
)
---
array (
  0 => 'k',
  1 => 'jhfdb',
)
---
```